# Causing transitions when sprites collide in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering when I use CGRectIntersectsRect and two object collide, where in my update method should I put the transition if it's possible? I want to use this for when my character collides with an enemy, a game over menu appears.

Comment: that truly depends on your design, context and object model. If you detect collision in a CCSprite extension, it is probably not the right place to trigger such high level actions as a game-over menu. I would suggest posting a notification using NSNotificationCenter, that your controller will will register to receive. Then let the controller take the appropriate actions.

Answer (score 0):

The best place is in your main game loop (Probably is the scene that run your game).

If you are checking the collision in this main game loop, just call a function to itself. If you are checking the collision in a method of the sprite that are colliding, then post a NSNotification or use the delegate approach.